Install Sudo and apt-get in bluehost server
I have been trying to install sudo command and apt-get command in my Linux server by below command,
yum install sudo or apt-get install sudo

But I am getting below error,
-bash: apt: command not found

My server is hosted in Bluehost, and I am not sure at which path I need to install sudo command. I checked /etc/ folder on server, but I don't found any sudo related file there.
Can anyone share link to install sudo command on server or guide me?

Hi you have different ways to do it
You can use pkgs.org website and try to find your favourite things like apt or sudo and for first use:
yum install wget

And after install wget you can open the pkgs.org web and for example search for sudo and open your own os and copy the download link and use this command to first download that command file you want:
wget [Url-copyed]

And then use dpkg with -i switch:
dpkg -i [installed-file-name]

And after that this command will install it on your os and then you can delete that file you were downloaded
Second way:
You can install winscp on your Windows desktop and install that file from pkgs.org on your Microsoft system and connect with winscp to your server and then drag that file you were downloaded and drop to your different side into your server and then like recent way use dpkg with -i switch to install the command.
Note: It's possible that thing you want have some dependencys and you must install all dependencys like this from pkgs.org
Have a great day.
